# Missing namespace of existing library, Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an auxiliar project that contains Java libraries used in the project. That project contains a folder with a `mbwaysdk.jar` and a `WheelPicker-1.1.1.aar`  in it.

After building that project, it generates the .NET classes for the `mbwaysdk.jar` without any problem, but the classes of `WheelPicker-1.1.1.aar` don't show up. I've checked and the `obj/Debug/generated/src` folder contains the file classes for the `mbwaysdk.jar` and `WheelPicker-1.1.1.aar` libraries.

Within Visual Studio, the namespace `Com.Aigestudio.Wheelpicker` isn't recognized, although the project succesfully builds and deploys to devices, and any usage of the `Com.Aigestudio.Wheelpicker` views and methods works. While in debug I'm able to inspect the object, but unable to navigate to the class.

What can be causing this issue?